# Salesforce Test Class's and codecoverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

I inherited a Salesforce and Salesforce code. I am trying to locate which test classes correspond to the classes. The people who wrote the code didnt name the test classes with a prefix or suffix of the test class so I am unable to tell which classes are to which Test Classes. Is there a way to find this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests can cover more code than just what they explicitly test. For example, DML operations in a test context will implicitly test the triggers behind those DML operations, even if the test is on an unrelated class.

To get what tests cover a class, go to the class in the Developer Console, and click the "Code Coverage" button on the upper-right-hand side.

[image]

You'll see a list of the tests which over that class.

[image]

From here, you can try and piece together what covers what. Make sure you've run your tests first. This won't help you get coverage info for all classes in the org, but will help you chip away at the org, class by class.